# FFMPEG - convert video with multiple audio and subtitles

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a MKV video file with 1x video track, 3x audio tracks and 2x subtitle tracks.

Now, I use the code below convert the video to `x265` but sadly have no control over which audio and subtitles to convert. Can someone advise how I can tweak the statement to use audio track #0:3 and subtitle #0:4?

`ffmpeg -i INPUT.mkv -c:v libx265 -c:a copy -x265-params crf=25 OUTPUT.mkv`

This is what the `.mkv` file contains:

```
  Stream #0:0(jpn): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x692 [SAR 1:1 DAR 320:173], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : English 2.0 channel AAC (Original)
  Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      title           : English 2.0 channel AAC (New)
  Stream #0:3(jpn): Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      title           : Japanese 2.0 channel AAC
  Stream #0:4(eng): Subtitle: ass (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Signs/Karaoke [Kametsu]
  Stream #0:5(eng): Subtitle: ass
    Metadata:
      title           : Re-styled [Kametsu]
  Stream #0:6: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : nyala.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:7: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : fontastique.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:8: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : ARIALNB.TTF
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:9: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : BorisBlackBloxx.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:10: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : CODE2000.TTF
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:11: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : CronosPro-Semibold.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> hevc (libx265))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:4 -> #0:2 (ass (ssa) -> ass (ssa))
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-map` option. These two commands will do the same thing but use different `-map` syntax:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.mkv -map 0:0 -map 0:3   -map 0:4   -c:v libx265 -c:a copy -c:s copy -x265-params crf=25 OUTPUT.mkv
ffmpeg -i INPUT.mkv -map 0:v -map 0:a:2 -map 0:s:0 -c:v libx265 -c:a copy -c:s copy -x265-params crf=25 OUTPUT.mkv
```

See [FFmpeg Wiki: Map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map) for more info.